# How to access value of group access token inside GitLab CI job?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, token

I am testing accessing the package and container repository/registry from different project. I do know that CI job token access can be adjusted in the project settings. However, I would like to have a quick solution that does not involve tweaking each and every new project's settings to whitelist this and that repository. Hence I decided to use **group access tokens**.

I have multiple projects inside a group (some are inside subgroups). All group and project settings are default.

In one repository I am producing an image that I would like to use in a build CI job (through a Dockerfile's `FROM`) in another one. I created a GAT with `API` rights and `Developer` role. According to [permissions documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) this should be enough for both reading and writing packages and images.

My CI job looks like this:

```
build-service:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: ['']
  tags:
    - asprunner
  rules:
    # Build base image only if the Dockerfile or CICD config file have changed and been pushed to the cloud branch
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev
      when: on_success
  script:
    - echo "Building image for service X using Kaniko"
    - |
      export BASE_REGISTRY_URL=registry.company.com/mygroup/base-service
      export BASE_TOKEN_NAME=CI_GROUP_API
      export BASE_TOKEN_VALUE=$(CI_GROUP_API)

      echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"},\"${BASE_REGISTRY_URL}\":{\"username\":\"${BASE_TOKEN_NAME}\",\"password\":\"${BASE_TOKEN_VALUE}\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor
       --context .
       --dockerfile Dockerfile
       --insecure
       --skip-tls-verify
       --skip-tls-verify-pull
       --insecure-pull
       --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:v0.1"
```

where `registry.company.com/mygroup/base-service` points at the container registry where my base image (inherited by my `Dockerfile` in this CI job and repo) is located.

I get the following error

```
$ export BASE_REGISTRY_URL=registry.company.com/mygroup/base-service # collapsed multi-line command
/bin/sh: eval: line 147: CI_GROUP_API: not found
CI_GROUP_API
$ /kaniko/executor --context . --dockerfile Dockerfile --insecure --skip-tls-verify --skip-tls-verify-pull --insecure-pull --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:v0.1"
INFO[0000] Retrieving image manifest registry.company.com/mygroup/base-service:v1.0 
INFO[0000] Retrieving image registry.company.com/mygroup/base-service:v1.0 from registry registry.company.com 
error building image: unable to complete operation after 0 attempts, last error: GET https://gitlab.company.com/jwt/auth?scope=repository%3Aiosb%2Fiad%2F3dpipeline%2Fbase-service%3Apull&service=container_registry: DENIED: access forbidden
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

I notice that I cannot retrieve `CI_GROUP_API`'s value. How would I make it work in a similar fashion like the `CI_JOB_TOKEN`.

The only solution I have found is to create a group CI/CD variable with the same name and value as the GAT.

Is there a more direct way to access the GAT from a CI job?